# Using a parameter with apoc.periodic.commit giving OutOfMemoryError

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour when using apoc.periodic.commit to delete all relationships (around 2million) from a single node, and then follow it up with a call to delete that node:

```
MATCH(node:SomeNodeType) 
WITH ID(node) AS nodeId
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (node:SomeNodeType)-[rel:NodeRel]->() WHERE ID(node) = $nodeId
WITH rel LIMIT $limit DELETE rel RETURN COUNT(rel)",
{limit:2000, params: { nodeId: nodeId}})
YIELD updates
MATCH (node:SomeNodeType) WHERE ID(node) = 4 DETACH DELETE node
RETURN updates
```

This results in a Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError.
My Neo4j instance is running in Docker, and to force this error with smaller data sizes I gave it 512m of memory using : - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m environment variable. Giving it 2Gb instead gives the same result, the above query fails and the following succeeds:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (node:SomeNodeType)-[rel:NodeRel]->() WHERE ID(node) = 4
WITH rel LIMIT $limit DELETE rel RETURN COUNT(rel)",
{limit:2000})
YIELD updates
MATCH (node:SomeNodeType) WHERE ID(node) = 4 DETACH DELETE node
RETURN updates
```

The only real difference between the queries is the parameter being input into apoc.periodic.commit to match the SomeNodeType, and I can't think of a reason why this would cause the query to use so much more memory. Does anybody have any more insight as to what is going on here?

Using Neo4j 4.0.0 docker image with APOC 4.0.0.4

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have just one node with label SomeNodeType?

Comment: Yes, definitely only 1 SomeNodeType.